# My Binary Tree has Linker errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, data-structures

I have a BinarySearchTree class and a BinaryNode class. My code is correct regarding its syntax. But on compiling, it generates linker errors. I only tried Visual Studio 2012's compilor and I want the same compilor to be use because my entire project is on VS2012. I wrote the code of classes and all the functions below and firstly, the errors as follows::

1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall BinarySearchTree::BinarySearchTree(int const &)" (??0?$BinarySearchTree@H@@QAE@ABH@Z) referenced in function _main

1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall BinarySearchTree::~BinarySearchTree(void)" (??1?$BinarySearchTree@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall BinarySearchTree::insert(int const &)" (?insert@?$BinarySearchTree@H@@QAEXABH@Z) referenced in function _main

1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall BinarySearchTree::remove(int const &)" (?remove@?$BinarySearchTree@H@@QAEXABH@Z) referenced in function _main

1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall BinarySearchTree::printTree(void)const " (?printTree@?$BinarySearchTree@H@@QBEXXZ) referenced in function _main

1>c:\users\aftab electronics\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\BST\Debug\BST.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals

```
//BinarySearchTree.h
#ifndef _BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H
#define _BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H
#include<iostream>

//Binary Node and Forward Declaration
template<class EType> class BinarySearchTree;

template<class EType> class BinaryNode{
    EType element;
    BinaryNode* left, *right;

public:
    BinaryNode(const EType& theElement, BinaryNode* lt, BinaryNode *rt):element(theElement),left(lt),right(rt){}
    friend class BinarySearchTree<EType>;
};

template<class EType> class BinarySearchTree{
public:
    BinarySearchTree(const EType& notFound);
    BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree& rhs);
    ~BinarySearchTree();

    const EType& findMin() const;
    const EType& findMax() const;
    const EType& find(const EType& x) const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void printInOrder() const;
    void insert(const EType& x);
    void remove(const EType& x);
    void printTree() const;
    void printTree(BinaryNode<EType>* ) const;
    BinaryNode<EType>* clone(BinaryNode<EType> *t) const;

    const BinarySearchTree& operator= (const BinarySearchTree& rhs);

private:
    BinaryNode<EType>* root;
    //ITEM_NOT_FOUND object used to signal failed finds
    const EType ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
    const EType& elementAt(BinaryNode<EType>* t) const;
    void insert(const EType& x, BinaryNode<EType>* &t);
    void remove(const EType& x, BinaryNode<EType>* &t);
    BinaryNode<EType>* findMin(BinaryNode<EType>* t) const;
    BinaryNode<EType>* findMax(BinaryNode<EType>* t) const;
    BinaryNode<EType>* find(const EType& x, BinaryNode<EType>* t) const;
    void makeEmpty(BinaryNode<EType>* &t);
    void printInOrder(BinaryNode<EType>* t);
    void makeEmpty();
};
#endif
```

And then, the implementation file BinarySearchTree.cpp is as below:

```
#include "BinarySearchTree.h"
#include<iostream>

//Construct The Tree
template<class EType> BinarySearchTree<EType>::BinarySearchTree(const EType& notFound):ITEM_NOT_FOUND(notFound), root(NULL){}

//Copy COnstructor
template<class EType> BinarySearchTree<EType>::BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree<EType>& rhs):root(NULL),ITEM_NOT_FOUND(rhs.ITEM_NOT_FOUND)
{
    *this = rhs;
}

//Destructor
template<class EType> BinarySearchTree<EType>::~BinarySearchTree(){makeEmpty();}

//Insert x into the Tree, Duplicates are iqnored
template<class EType> void BinarySearchTree<EType>::insert(const EType& x){insert(x, root);}

//Remove X from the Tree. Nothing is done if x is not found.
template<class EType> void BinarySearchTree<EType>::remove(const EType& x){remove(x, root);}

//Find the smallest item in the tree. Return it. Return ITEM_NOT_FOUND if empty
template<class EType> const EType& BinarySearchTree<EType>::findMin() const
{
    return elementAt (findMin(root));
}

//Find largest item in tree. return or return ITEM_NOT_FOUND if empty
template<class EType> const EType& BinarySearchTree<EType>::findMax() const {
    return elementAt(findMax(root));
}

//Find item x in the tree. return the matching or ITEM_NOT_FOUND if not exist
template<class EType> const EType& BinarySearchTree<EType>::find(const EType& x) const{
    return elementAt(find(x,root));
}

//Make the tree logically empty
template<class EType> void BinarySearchTree<EType>::makeEmpty(){
    makeEmpty(root);
}

//Test if the tree is logically empty. Return true otherwise false
template<class EType> bool BinarySearchTree<EType>::isEmpty() const{
    return root == NULL;
}

//Print Tree in sorted order
template<class EType> void BinarySearchTree<EType>::printTree() const {
    if (isEmpty())
        cout<< "Empty Tree\n";
    else
        printTree(root);
}

//Deep Copy
template<class EType> const BinarySearchTree<EType>& BinarySearchTree<EType>::operator=(const BinarySearchTree<EType>& rhs){

    if(this != &rhs){
        makeEmpty();
        root = clone(rhs.root);
    }
    return *this;
}

//Internal Method to get element in field in node t. Return the element field or ITEM_NOT_FOUND if t is NULL
template<class EType> const EType& BinarySearchTree<EType>::elementAt(BinaryNode<EType> *t) const {
    if(t == NULL) return ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
    else return t->element;
}

//internal method to insert into a subtree. x is to be inserted, t roots the tree. 
template<class EType> void BinarySearchTree<EType>::insert(const EType& x, BinaryNode<EType>* &t) {
    if(t==NULL)
        t = new BinaryNode<EType>(x, NULL, NULL);
    else if(x < t->element)
        insert(x, t->left);
    else if(t->left < x)
        insert(x, t->right);
    else
        ; // duplicate do nothing
}

//Internal method to remove from a subtree. x is the item to remove. t is the node that roots the tree. 
template<class EType> void BinarySearchTree<EType>::remove(const EType& x, BinaryNode<EType>* &t) {
    if(t == NULL) return; //Item not found, do nothing
    if(x < t->element) 
        remove(x, t->left);
    else if(t->element < x) 
        remove(x, t->right);
    else if(t->left != NULL && t->right != NULL) 
    {
        t->element = findMin(t->right)->element;
        remove(t->element, t->right);   
    }
    else {
        BinaryNode<EType>* nodeToDelete = t;
        t = (t->left != NULL) ? t->left : t->right;
        delete nodeToDelete;

    }
}
// Internal method to find the smallest item in a subtree t. return node containing the smallest item. 
template<class EType> BinaryNode<EType>* BinarySearchTree<EType>::findMin(BinaryNode<EType>* t) const {
    if(t == NULL) return NULL;
    if(t->left == NULL) return t;
    return findMin(t->left);
}


// Internal method to find the largest item in a subtree t. Return node containg the largest item. 
template<class EType> BinaryNode<EType>* BinarySearchTree<EType>::findMax(BinaryNode<EType>* t) const{
    if(t != NULL)
        while(t->right != NULL)
            t = t->right;
    return t;
}

//Internal method to find an item in a subtree. x is searchee. t node roots the tree. return node containg match item
template<class EType> BinaryNode<EType>* BinarySearchTree<EType>::find(const EType& x, BinaryNode<EType> *t) const {
    if(t == NULL) return NULL;
    else if(x < t->element) return find(x, t->left);
    else if(t->element < x) return find(x, t->right);
    else return t; //Match

    //// NON RECURSIVE VERSION ///
    /*
        while(t != NULL)
            if(x < t->element)
                t = t->left;
            else if(t->element < x)
                t = t->right;
            else
                return t; // Match
        return NULL; //No Match
    */
}

//INternal method to make subtree empty
template<class EType> void BinarySearchTree<EType>::makeEmpty(BinaryNode<EType>* &t){
    if(t != NULL){
        makeEmpty(t->left);
        makeEmpty(t->right);
        delete t;
    }
    t = NULL;
}

//Internal method to print subtree rooted at t in sorted order
template<class EType> void BinarySearchTree<EType>::printTree(BinaryNode<EType>* t) const {
    if(t != NULL){
        printTree(t->left);
        cout<<t->element<<endl;
        printTree(t->right);
    }
}

//Internal method to clone subtree
template<class EType> BinaryNode<EType>* BinarySearchTree<EType>::clone(BinaryNode<EType> *t) const{
    if(t == NULL) return NULL;
    else return new BinaryNode<EType>(t->element, clone(t->left), clone(t->right));
}
```

After it, the source.cpp file that contains main program is :

```
#include<iostream>
#include "BinarySearchTree.h"

int main(){

    const int ITEM_NOT_FOUND = -9999;
    BinarySearchTree<int> t(ITEM_NOT_FOUND);
    int NUMS = 30;
    int i;

    std::cout<<"Inserting Elements (1 to 30) in the trees ..... )"<<std::endl;
    for(i=0; i<=NUMS; i++)
        t.insert(i);

    std::cout<<"Printing the values of nodes in tree...."<<std::endl;
    t.printTree();

    std::cout<<"\n\nRemoving the even number elements in the tree ..........."<<std::endl;
    for(i=0; i<=NUMS; i+=2)
        t.remove(i);

    std::cout<<"Printing the values of nodes in tree....."<<std::endl;
    t.printTree();

system("pause");

}
```

please tell me how to resolve these linker errors.

Comment: This question is totally different from the one that you supposed to be matching it. My question is about linker errors and your referred question is about some template headers.. please open it again. Im in trouble. I want answer. thanks

Comment: The answer is that templates have to be implemented in the header file.

Comment: which mean there is no need of .cpp file?

Comment: I used your trick. thanks. I implemented some templates in header and it runs now but some templates still are implemented separately in cpp. Why it is now running becaues others still are implemented templates in cpp???